# UBUNTU 22.04 NCURSES_TINFO_6.2.20211010 not found

Tags: package-management, 22.04, shared-library

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu system yesterday to 22.04 LTS. Everything was working like a charm before the upgrade. However, after the upgrade apparently the library `libncurses` got updated from 6.2 to 6.3.

The problem is that some applications I have are throwing an exception and they crash with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 53, in __init__
  File "ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
OSError: /usr/local/softwarename/libtinfo.so.5: version `NCURSES_TINFO_6.2.20211010' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

and this what Ubuntu 22.04 by default has:

```
x@y:~$ find /usr/lib/ -iname libncurses*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesada.so.6.2.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
```

I have tried though to install manually the package 6.2 from [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libncurses6_6.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html), however things did not work and the whole system started to throw unexpected crash reports saying that I have installed packages out-of-date and need to be fixed and updated.

I would appreciate any tip or suggestion how to overcome the problem.